# Find img src and append to href

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I am using the jQuery Plugin Galleriffic with a content management system. I need to generate the thumbnails with jQuery.

I basically need to use jQuery to look inside a div, find all the images, wrap each image in an `<a>` and a `<li>` around that. Find the img src and input it into the href of the `<a>`.

So each image in the end will look like this:

```
<li><a href="link to img src"><img src="image src" /></a></li>
```

Comment: So, basically you need someone to write this code for you?

Comment: have you tried anything already? This is quite easy :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps something like this :

```
$('img').each(function(){
    $(this).wrap('<li><a href="' + $(this).attr('src') + '"></a></li>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

See a **working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/usmanhalalit/UYQqw/1/

```
$(function(){
    $('#imgs img').each(function(){
       $(this).wrap('<li><a href="'+$(this).attr('src')+'">','</a><li>')
    });
});
```

Here is the demo markup I used

```
<img src="image src" />
<div id='imgs'>
    <img src="image src1" />
    <img src="image src2" />
    <img src="image src3" />
</div>
```

As you said you need to look inside a `div`, so it will do it only for `img` inside `#imgs` div above.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').each(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    var a = $('<a>', {
         href: this.src
    });
    $(this).appendTo(a);
    var li = $('<li>');
    a.appendTo(li);

    li.appendTo(parent);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/bAuwT/1/